# Need name of an anthology

Tags: story-identification, aliens, anthology-book

I'm trying to remember the name of an anthology of short stories about humans fighting an alien, insect-like race. I read the book in the late 1980s. There were about 10 stories.

One of the stories featured an imprisoned general who led an army of prisoners to turn the tide of the war. This was a very good story. It was centered around a general who was sent to a military prison for disobeying an order. When he arrived at the prison he observed the inmate population and befriended key individuals to help organize and rally them into a fighting unit. The prison was requested to help fight and turn the tide of the war. The prison army was feared by the aliens because the inmates fought with great virtuosity and no fear.

Another story was about a soldier who tested weapons, found many of them to be defective, and tried to find out why. The weapons were defective because some weapon manufacturers were in league with the aliens and this was discovered by the story’s protagonist. Agents of the crooked manufacturers also killed the protagonist's girlfriend.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Were the stories by different authors or one author? About how old is the book? How long ago did you read it? Why were so many of the weapons defective?

Comment: So this was a collection of stories but all with the same subject of this interstellar war against the insect-like aliens? Seems distinctive enough that someone might recognize it. When did you read it? How many stories? Any more details you can add about the story with the army of prisoners?

Comment: I read the book in the late 1980s.  There was about 10 stories.  The prison army was very good story.  It was centered around a general was sent to a military prison for disobeying an order. When he arrived the prison he observed the inmate population and befriended key individuals to help organize and rally them into an fighting unit.  The prison was requested to help fight and turn the tide of the war.  The prison army was feared by the aliens because the inmates fought with great virtuosity and no fear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convicted soldier serves his time and builds a new unit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125103/convicted-soldier-serves-his-time-and-builds-a-new-unit)

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 - we don't close story IDs as duplicates unless both questions have confirmed an answer (and that it is the same answer).